# square elements of a non square pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to square the elements of a non square(m*n dimension) pandas dataframe but each time i try the following I get an error that says

```
1) np.power(errorR, 2)
2) errorR**2 



ValueError: input must be a square array
```

is there a good solution for this?

Comment: Can you add some sample data? 3-4 rows.

Comment: Also it seems error is in code before (or after), because `np.power(errorR, 2)` and `errorR**2` working perfectly in non square df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this in the jupyter environment and it worked after restarting the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Try `df.applymap(lambda x: x**2)`

Comment: Not even. You can use `df ** 2`, but unless OP's problem statement is clear, there's no point.